# How to get global Windows I/O statistics?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

There is a WinAPI function [`GetProcessIoCounters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683218(v=vs.85).aspx) that provides details of all I/O operations of a given process: number of read/write operations and number of bytes read/written since the process started. Most likely Task Manager uses this function to show these numbers:

[image: Task Manager]

---

Is there a relatively easy way to get the same or similar stats, but for the **whole system** since it started?

Please note, that it is not the same as enumerate all current processes and sum up results of `GetProcessIoCounters`, because there are processes that start, run for a while and finish. At the time when I call `GetProcessIoCounters` such processes don't exist anymore, but I would like to know the overall I/O of the system.

I intend to collect these stats every hour or so and log them into the database for future analysis and to help with debugging.

I'm looking for a method that works on Windows XP without WMI (we use a significantly cut-down Windows XP Embedded), but if such method exists only for later versions of Windows, please share it. Eventually it will be useful.

**Update**

I tried the `DeviceIoControl(IOCTL_DISK_PERFORMANCE)` method suggested by [Jerry Coffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179910/jerry-coffin).

I had to run [`diskperf.exe -Y`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hh875645.aspx) to make it work. I didn't even have to reboot, but without it `DeviceIoControl` was failing with `GetLastError=31` (A device attached to the system is not functioning.) `DeviceIoControl` continued to work after reboot without the need to run `diskperf.exe -Y` again, but the first call to `DeviceIoControl` after reboot returned zeros in all fields (BytesRead, BytesWritten, ReadCount, WriteCount). Further calls returned non-zero stats. Obviously, there was some substantial disk activity when the system started, but it was not counted. So, it looks like that the first call to `DeviceIoControl` after reboot indeed enables/starts the counters.

If I run `diskperf.exe -N`, then `DeviceIoControl` stops working immediately without the need to reboot. When I run `diskperf.exe -Y`, then `DeviceIoControl` works fine again.

Now the question is: what `diskperf.exe -Y` does and how to do the same thing in my program?

**Update 2**

I exported the whole registry after `diskperf.exe -Y` and after `diskperf.exe -N` and looked for the difference. The only difference I could find was in one key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PartMgr
"EnableCounterForIoctl"=dword:00000001
```

`diskperf.exe -Y` adds this key, `diskperf.exe -N` removes it.

I tried to add/delete this key directly into the registry.

---

If the key doesn't exist and `DeviceIoControl` doesn't work (after I run `diskperf.exe -N`) and I add this key like this:

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PartMgr" /v EnableCounterForIoctl /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

, then `DeviceIoControl` begins to work immediately.

If the key exists and `DeviceIoControl` works (after I run `diskperf.exe -Y`) and I delete this key like this:

```
reg delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PartMgr" /v EnableCounterForIoctl
```

then `DeviceIoControl` continues to work and the returned statistics keeps growing. Until reboot.

`diskperf.exe` must be doing something else in addition to changing the registry value, something like forcing the flush/refresh of the registry. In my case I care about enabling these counters and it seems to work with the simple adding of the registry key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the data one disk at a time using DeviceIoControl, something like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    HANDLE dev = CreateFile("\\\\.\\C:", 
        FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, 
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
        NULL, 
        OPEN_EXISTING, 
        0, 
        NULL);

    DISK_PERFORMANCE disk_info { };
    DWORD bytes;

    if (dev == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening disk\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (!DeviceIoControl(dev, 
            IOCTL_DISK_PERFORMANCE, 
            NULL, 
            0, 
            &disk_info, 
            sizeof(disk_info), 
            &bytes, 
            NULL))
    {
        std::cerr << "Failure in DeviceIoControl\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));
    std::cout << "Bytes read: " << disk_info.BytesRead.QuadPart << "\n";
    std::cout << "Bytes written: " << disk_info.BytesWritten.QuadPart << "\n";
}
```

For example, on my machine right now, this shows:

```
Bytes read: 15,768,173,568
Bytes written: 22,370,663,424
```

Experimentally, the results I'm getting look reasonable. For example, after plugging in a flash drive and opening a preview of some pictures on it, I get:

```
Bytes read: 3,956,736
Bytes written: 0
```

To get the data for all drives currently visible in the system, add a call to `GetLogicalDrives` or `GetLogicalDriveStrings`, and call code like this in a loop, but filling in the appropriate drive letter for each call.

This still isn't guaranteed to be all the data since the system was booted though. For example, if you eject a removable disk, information about what was read from/written to that drive is lost. If you plug it back in, you'll only get data about what was read/written since the last time it was plugged in.

I'm not at all sure you're going to be able to do a whole lot better than that though, at least without doing a fair amount of extra work to collect data periodically and keep track of when disks are ejected and inserted and such. When a disk is ejected, I suspect Windows pretty much throws away all the statistics about that drive, so if it's later plugged back in, Windows no longer *has* stats about what was done with it prior to ejection.

Likewise, if a disk has been ejected so it's not currently visible, this won't be able to open it to start with, so it won't be able to retrieve any stats about that drive either.

Comment: Thank you! In my case I don't have removable disks, so this is not an issue. The only slight concern is this phrase in the docs: [`IOCTL_DISK_PERFORMANCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365183(v=vs.85).aspx) control code **enables** performance counters that provide disk performance information. And there is `IOCTL_DISK_PERFORMANCE_OFF` control code that **disables** performance counters. I'll check how it works. Maybe to get meaningful results I'll have to call `DeviceIoControl(IOCTL_DISK_PERFORMANCE)` right after reboot to initiate gathering of the stats.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov: Yeah, I saw that--but at least in some quick testing, it seemed to produce reasonable looking results as shown above.

Comment: I tested how `DeviceIoControl(IOCTL_DISK_PERFORMANCE)` works. Please see the update in the question. Do you know what `diskperf.exe -Y` does and how to do the same thing in my program?

Comment: It looks like `diskperf.exe -Y` adds a value `"EnableCounterForIoctl"=dword:00000001` to the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PartMgr`. Thank you for showing the `DeviceIoControl(IOCTL_DISK_PERFORMANCE)` - it turns out to be just what I needed.

Comment: This is cool. I'm confused about why you're using imbue(locale("") near the bottom though. Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck: It sets `std::cout` to format the numbers with thousands separators (or suitably for the locale you've configured, anyway).

Comment: Fantastically helpful answer.  I didn't even have a C++ compiler on my machine but I followed instructions at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp got MinGW installed and compiled this code sample in VSCode in 20 minutes.  The code worked perfectly but I did (on Win10) get an error on the cout.imbue call.  I just commented it out and the code ran great.  Thanks for this great answer.